# Navigation links with Mysql, PHP, Javascript and Iframe together

Tags: javascript, php, navigationbar

I am trying to list **navigation links** as targeting my **Iframe** with javascript.

As you see, the selected *distinct product categories* will be each item on the navigation bar.

I tried everything but it doesn't work. Can you solve this small code?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'solsten');
            $sql = "select distinct productcategori from products";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
                    echo "<div id='menu'>";
    while($myRow = $result->fetch_array())
                    {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        echo "<li style='display: inline;'>< a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='goto('imagegallery.php?categori=".$myRow['productcategori']."') <h4>".$myRow["productcategori"]."</h4></a> </li>";
                        echo "</ul>";

                        } 
                    echo "</div>"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Oh mean this code gives an error by "      

    < a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='goto('imagegallery.php?kategori=Orhangen') "

Comment: Can I use javascript and PHP together?

Comment: What is the error? PHP is server-side and JavaScript is client-side

Comment: None of them errors. My navigation just escapes and it says < a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='goto('imagegallery.php?categori=Orhangen') "        I think, there is something wrong with this "go to" part.

Comment: It can get the right category name but it doesn't show it in my navigation bar.

Comment: `goto()` is a function. Do you have a `goto()` function defined?

Comment: Yes. function goto(url) {
    document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentWindow.location.replace(url);
}

Comment: Have you tried it without the iframe?

Comment: Yes, and now. It works, but the links wont open in my Iframe. I will see now.

Comment: This was the right code...    echo "<li style='display: inline;'><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='goto('imagegallery.php?kategori=".$myRow['productcategori']."')'> <h4>".$myRow["productcategori"]."</h4></a> </li>";

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.